# Prove that this space of functions is closed in $C_{B}(X, \mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C_0(X,\mathbb{R})$ be the space of continuous functions $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ that go to $0$ at infinity, i. e. for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a compact $E\subset X$ such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for every $x\not\in E$.
So the conclusion is that $C_0(X,\mathbb{R})$ is a closed subspace of $C_B(X,\mathbb{R})$.

I was triying to use that If we have a compact subspace then it should be closed, but I think it will be more difficult to prove compactness, than closeness, And I don't have any other equivalence for closeness. Then my question is How can I prove this ?

And other thing, Where am I going to use that $E$ is compact?

Now I am triying to prove that this space is complete, but the thing is that I don't know how to get the result with the hypotheses I've got

Can someone help me to prove this?

I have realize the following argument, let's take a sequence such that it converges to some function $f$ and we will proof that it is in $C_0(X,\mathbb{R})$, for that we fix $x \notin E $ and then we proceed as follows

$$|f(x)|=|f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)| \le |f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)|\le \frac{\epsilon}{2}+ \frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

Now the question is **Am I right in this?, and How can I prove that $C_0(X,\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace of $C_B(X,\mathbb{R})$?**

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: $C_0(X,\mathbb{R})$ is generally not compact. You can show that $C_0(X,\mathbb{R})$ is a complete subspace of $C_B(X,\mathbb{R})$, or you can show that its complement is open.

Comment: Please define $C_B(X, \mathbb R).$

Comment: Ok, I will define that set :) give a second :)

Comment: $C_B(X,\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all continous and bounded functions from $X \to Y$

Comment: Thanks Daniel Fischer, If I get stuck with that Can I let you know ?

Comment: @DanielFischer I think is a little bit hard to prove compactness :(

Comment: subspace should be clear. As for closed subspace, your argument isn't bad. Just write it down properly. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and find the right $E$ and the right $n$.

Comment: To show that $C_0$ is a closed subspace of $C_B$, assume that $f \in C_B$ is a limit point of $C_0$. We need to show that $f \in C_0$. By definition of limit point, there is a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions in $C_0$ converging (in the metric on $C_B$) to $f$. Thus $(f_n)$ has the property that for every $\epsilon > 0$, we will have $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Now use the fact that the $f_n$'s are all in $C_0$.

Comment: Ok :) thanks a lot , and @Bungo could you please continue with your argument :)

Comment: I can write it up as an answer if you like, I wasn't sure if you were looking for hints or a solution.

Comment: And @user251257 what do you mean by find $E$ and $n$ ?

Comment: @Bungo An answer please :)

Comment: @user162343: $E$ depends on $\epsilon$ and the function... and $\|f_n - f\| < \epsilon / 2$ isn't true for every $n$, isn't it? You omitted important details in your argument.

Comment: Well can you post an aswer with those details please?

Answer (score 3):

I presume that you are using the uniform metric on $C_B$: if $f,g$ are two functions in $C_B$, then their distance is defined as
$$d(f,g) = \sup_{x \in X}|f(x) - g(x)|$$

First note that $C_0$ is a subspace of $C_B$. To see this, let $f$ be any function in $C_0$. Then $f$ is continuous and $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ outside some compact set $E \subseteq X$. Since a continuous function on a compact set is bounded, $f$ is bounded on $E$, say $|f(x)| < M$ for all $x \in E$. Then $|f(x)| < \max(M, \epsilon)$ for all $x \in X$.

To show that $C_0$ is a **closed** subspace of $C_B$, assume that $f \in C_B$ is a limit point of $C_0$. We need to show that $f \in C_0$.

So, fix $\epsilon > 0$. The goal is to show that $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ outside some compact subset of $X$. Since $f$ is a limit point of $C_0$, there is a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions in $C_0$ such that $d(f_n, f) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. So, there is some $N$ such that $d(f_n, f) < \epsilon/2$ for all $n \geq N$. In particular, $d(f_N, f) < \epsilon / 2$.

Now, $f_N \in C_0$, so there is some compact set $E \subseteq X$ such that $|f_N(x)| < \epsilon / 2$ for all $x \not\in E$.

Therefore, by the triangle inequality, for all $x \not\in E$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}
|f(x)| &\leq |f(x) - f_N(x)| + |f_N(x)| \\
& \leq |f(x) - f_N(x)| + \epsilon / 2 \\
&\leq \sup_{x \in X}|f(x)- f_N(x)| + \epsilon / 2\\
&= d(f, f_N) + \epsilon / 2 \\
&< \epsilon / 2 + \epsilon / 2 \\
&= \epsilon
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Just let me check it, and if I have some doubts can I let you know?

Comment: Well my first question jajajajaj, where do you use the set $E$?, I mean I think that your proof focuses on the definition of limit 0 at $\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and not in the one of the functional space, or am I wrong?

Comment: Rigth jajaja :) let me continue checking, Does it matters if I delay until tomorrow?, is because here is a little bit late :)

Comment: @user162343: Sure, leave a comment and I'll respond when I see it :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot and yes $X$ is not $\mathbb{R}$